# pybind11 convert python object to C++ struct equivalent

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I'm trying use Pybind11 to pass an object generated in python to C++ and have it converted to proper `struct` types, here's my python class:

```
class Token(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Token(type: {self.type}, value: {self.value!r}, line: {self.lineno}, pos: {self.pos})'

@dataclass
class TreeNode:
    type: NodeType
    tok: Token = None
    children: list = field(default_factory=list)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.type}" + (f"[{self.tok.value}]" if self.tok else "")
```

Here are the c++ struct equivalents:

```
struct Token
{
    char *type;
    char *value;
    int lineno;
    int pos;
};

struct TreeNode
{
    NodeType type;
    Token tok;
    std::vector<TreeNode *> children;
};
```

The pybind11 module definition:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(c_codegen, m)
{
    py::enum_<NodeType>(m, "NodeType")
        .value("CompilationUnit", NodeType::CompilationUnit)
        .value("Block", NodeType::Block)
        .value("Statement", NodeType::Statement)
        .value("Expression", NodeType::Expression)
        .value("Condition", NodeType::Condition)
        .value("Function", NodeType::Function)
        .value("FunctionCall", NodeType::FunctionCall)
        .value("Arguments", NodeType::Arguments)
        .value("Identifier", NodeType::Identifier)
        .value("Literal", NodeType::Literal)
        .value("Operator", NodeType::Operator);


    py::class_<Token>(m, "Token")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def_readwrite("type", &Token::type)
        .def_readwrite("value", &Token::value)
        .def_readwrite("lineno", &Token::lineno)
        .def_readwrite("pos", &Token::pos);

    py::class_<TreeNode>(m, "TreeNode")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def_readwrite("type", &TreeNode::type)
        .def_readwrite("tok", &TreeNode::tok)
        .def_readwrite("children", &TreeNode::children);

    m.def("processTreeNode", &processTreeNode, "Test func");
}


void processTreeNode(TreeNode &root)
{
    std::cout << root.type << std::endl;
}
```

I want to be able to send an instance of `TreeNode` class from Python to C++ to the `processTreeNode` function and get struct instance on the other end which I can work with. This compiles but I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/path/codegen_test.py", line 30, in <module>
    c_codegen.processNodeType(NodeType.Statement)
TypeError: processNodeType(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: c_codegen.NodeType) -> None
```

The error just says the types are incompatible but doesn't tell what's wrong with my Python type I'm sending. Do I need to change my C++ structs to classes for this to work? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You cant mix those types. The C++ defined and the Python defined types are two distinct types.

Actually, you either have to write your C++ function to accept a dataclass (a `pybind11::object` type) and call `getattr` to obtain all field values. So esentially disentangle it manually and convert it to a C++ type.

As far as I know, pybind11 does not automatically convert dataclasses.

Instead you have to work with the C++ types (`c_codegen.TreeNode` and `c_codegen.Token`, etc..) directly, instead of the Python ones.

The issue is that in Python all objects are references, so just converting (i.e. copying) an object will not be a valid strategy in general: When the C++ makes modifications and you expect the Python side to see the modifications this will not work with pybind11 making copies.

Example:

```
node.tok.value = 1
```

This first calls getattr on `node` to obtain a reference to the field `tok`. Then setattr is called on the returned object to set `value` to 1. If the first getattr returns a copy of `tok` the modification will not be visible in the object `node`. So either C++ or Python actually need `views` of the same unederlying object. One cannot make copies. So your strategy of having two types in Python and C++ and converting between these two on the C++/Python boundary cannot work.